HP NonStop NOWAIT I-O
Is it possible to write a NOWAIT I-O in HP NonStop COBOL?
I have a task to write a program to generate three "reports" [CSV files to be downloaded to a desktop for use in EXCEL].  I think I have one of four ways to do this.

Run the program three times with different input
Call subroutines each of which will produce a different CSV file.
Run the program once, build on O/P file; and then, SORT the output into three different CSV files. or
Run a requester and three servers [non Pathway] with each of the servers generating a report.

If I choose option 4, I want to speed up the processing by doing a NOWAIT I-O in the requester.  I don't want to use an ENTER TAL construct and use a Guardian I-O if I can avoid it.  My TAL is rusty; and, I am working in a COBOL shop.
I want to know if I can issue a NOWAIT I-O WRITE from the requester to each of the servers and then execute an AWAITIO.
Is this doable; or if I solely use COBOL, am I stuck using WAITed I-O?
Thanks.
I haven't tried anything yet; I have just now sat down to plan and write this program.

Welcome to SO! Please have a look at the tour to learn about how this site works and why your question as it currently is does not meet the question criteria and is likely to be closed.
Site note: option1 seems to be the way to go, but as we don't have input/output data and no code at all we cannot be sure.
